# How To Create Function Repl in Java

Tags: java, user-input, prompt

This is a Peter Norvig's repl function:

```
def repl(prompt='lis.py> '):
    "A prompt-read-eval-print loop."
    while True:
        val = eval(parse(raw_input(prompt)))
        if val is not None: 
            print(schemestr(val))

def schemestr(exp):
    "Convert a Python object back into a Scheme-readable string."
    if isinstance(exp, List):
        return '(' + ' '.join(map(schemestr, exp)) + ')' 
    else:
        return str(exp)
```

Which works:

```
>>> repl()
lis.py> (define r 10)
lis.py> (* pi (* r r))
314.159265359
lis.py> (if (> (* 11 11) 120) (* 7 6) oops)
42
lis.py>
```

I'm trying to write program with the same functionality in Java, tried classes from Java docs, but nothing works like that; any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Download java 9. It's called JShell.

Comment: Java does not have a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) or an `eval()` method, and even if it did, it certainly would not evaluate non-Java code.

Comment: @Andreas *cough* [`jython`](http://www.jython.org/) *cough*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch True, and it comes with its own REPL: http://www.jython.org/docs/using/cmdline.html#command-line

Comment: Groovy or GroovyConsole can do it well

Comment: Current comments and answer focus on "Java REPL", I also interpreted it that way initially, but now I realize... Do you want a LISP REPL that you could call from Java?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't wanna JShell, I'm gonna write shell.

Answer (score 1):

A REPL is called REPL because it is a **L**oop that **R**eads and **E**valuates code and **P**rints the results. In Lisp, the code is literally:

```
(LOOP (PRINT (EVAL (READ))))
```

In an unstructured language, it would be something like:

```
#loop:
$code ← READ;
$res  ← EVAL($code);
        PRINT($res);
  GOTO #loop;
```

That's where the name comes from.

In Java, it would be something like:

```
while (true) {
  Code code  = read(System.in);
  Object res = eval(code);
  System.out.println(res);
}
```

But, there are no methods corresponding to `READ` or `EVAL` in Java or the JRE. You will have to write `read`, `eval`, and `Code` yourself. Note that `read` is essentially a parser for Java, and `eval` is an interpreter for Java. Both the syntax and the semantics for Java are described in the Java Language Specification, all you have to do is read the JLS and implement those two methods.

Comment: Agree with everything what's been said. I don't need Java repl, I just want my prompt looks the same like python's:  input("something") function.